# keras with theano backend runs lstm much slower on cpu

Tags: keras, theano

since keras with tensorflow backend can not reproduce results, i switch to theano. However, when i run the exactly same lstm model with exactly the same data,with theano backend is almost three times slower than with tensorflow backend. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running the command "conda install -y mkl"